# No internet access via IPv4, IPv6 works fine

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ipv6, ipv4

I ran into some troubles with my Ubuntu 18.10 machine. I have changed my ISP a few days ago and
more or less since then **I cannot connect to IPv4 websites anymore**, nor use any service requiring IPv4. When I use certain pages such as google everything works just fine, IPv6 services work as well. I tried to do some google research on this but I could not find an answer that was suitable for my problem.
I did not change any network properties and both windows and my old laptop (Ubuntu as well) are running fine with IPv4 in the same network. I sincerly hope someone could suggest what I can do about it.

Some informations that might be useful:

Running a `ping` delivers: `ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted` on any IPv4 website

Using `nslookup` delivers the IPv4 adress of every page i wish and if available the IPv6 adress as well. Using these for `ping` the IPv6 does work, while IPv4 won't, giving the error above.

`ifconfig` does not seem to deliver any strange outputs, same as usual

`/etc/resolv.conf` contains the following:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search fritz.box
```

The solution from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1278597/i-can-ping-ipv6-but-not-ipv4) does not work for me (disabling IPv4 and setting IPv6 to adress only)

**Edit 1:**
Output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:95:57:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.39/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp5s0
       valid_lft 863975sec preferred_lft 863975sec
    inet6 2003:d6:e713:2600:3ded:2f0a:4e4f:1396/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7178sec preferred_lft 1572sec
    inet6 fe80::c823:801b:7f13:fd8c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:62:66:bc:c1:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And `ip r` reads

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp5s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.39 metric 100
```

**Edit 2:**
`iptables -L -n` delivers

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The next funny thing now is, that after days of not working at all, **I can now connect to IPv4 websites in firefox again**. When I try `ping` such a site via console it just does nothing at all. No error mesage or anything else, just blinking cursor.
I did not use the OS for the last days, exept getting the cmd outputs above.

Comment: Are you only having issues with Ubuntu?  Is there a router between your ISP and this computer and if so was that replaced?

Comment: I'm only having this issue with Ubuntu on this one specific pc. Windows (Dualboot) and my other computer (again ubuntu) are working fine. The router (a fritzbox) was not replaced and seems properly.

Comment: Please post the complete output of `ip a` and `ip r` ...

Comment: I added both outputs to the post above :)

Comment: How bizarre - that all looks sane.  What about `iptables -L -n` ?

Comment: Added the output of ``iptables``. Funny thing now is, that firefox seems to connect to IPv4 webpages again. Ping is still not possible. This is so weird

Comment: Seeing the notes under your 2nd edit I'm now wondering whether there was something funky with the DHCP lease (and things maybe weren't properly reflected in the file system).  Have you tried rebooting it? ;)

Comment: Yes I did. :D Several times. That would be very embarrassing if rebooting would be the soulution.
Well, since it works now I sincerely thank you for your support! I'll flag this topic as solved now (it's my first post here, so may need a bit to find out how :D )

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue occured again and again after several days, I decieded to keep a look on `iptables`. It seemed like every few days or so, my system is replacing the default rules for something wihtout proper destination.

Each time this happens , I used `iptables -F` to recreate the default settings and everything works fine now :-)